# Delete the latest open graph read action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is able to create a read action successfully using the following code:

```
 FB.api('/me/xyz:listen_to&song=<?=curPageURL()?>','post');
```

I need to give a link to delete the same story. My issue is, how do i get the id of the latest story i added s i can delete it. Can I get this id via php?

I got the following code from google search, but cannot figure out how to get the id that is passed in to the function.

```
function deleteAction()
 {
 FB.api(
    '<?=$actionID ?>',
  'delete',
   function(response) {
     alert('action deleted')
   });
 }
```

Comment: When publishing your action, you’re getting the action_instance_id as a return. You should save that to your own database (connected to your user), so that you can look up his taken actions any time – and have the id when you need to delete it.

Comment: That may not not work for my case as i am doin this for every facebook-logged user who visits my site. I want it to be spontaneous i.e. i add a new story to the user's timeline and ask them if they would like to delete it. (The way yahoo does it). I dont think storing the values in a db would help since most of the visitors may not be registered on my website. I need a way to store the current visitor's most recently added action ONLY. This will enable me delete it easily if the user chooses to.

Comment: OK, you can always ask the Graph API for `/userid/app_namespace:actionname` to get the actions published for a user.